# 'Foreign' state for brand new disk in Dell R730

Tags: raid, hard-drive, dell-poweredge, dell, dell-openmanage

Trying to install additional drives into my R730 Dell Poweredge (none have failed, just need more space)

Inserted the disks and they all show as status 'Foreign' and the only option available is 'Blink' or 'Unblink'

Some sources refer to 'clear foreign config' but i can't see that as an option.  (Using OMSA whilst logged into the server, running Windows Server 2019)

Please help!

```
╔══════════════╦══════════════════════╦═════════╦══════════════╦═════════════════╦═════════╦══════════════╦═══════╦══════════╦════════════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦══════════════════════╦═══════════════════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═════════════╦══════════════╦═════════════════════════╦══════════════════╦═══════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════════╦══════════════════╦══════════════════╦══════════════════╦════════════════════════════════╗
║ Status       ║ Name                 ║ State   ║ Power Status ║ Tasks           ║ Execute ║ Bus Protocol ║ Media ║ Revision ║ T10 PI Capable ║ Certified ║ Capacity ║ Used RAID Disk Space ║ Available RAID Disk Space ║ Hot Spare ║ Vendor ID ║ Product ID  ║ Serial No.   ║ Part Number             ║ Negotiated Speed ║ Capable Speed ║ Sector Size ║ Manufacture Day ║ Manufacture Week ║ Manufacture Year ║ SAS Address      ║ Non-RAID HDD Disk Cache Policy ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║ Ok           ║ Physical Disk 0:1:0  ║ Online  ║ Spun Up      ║ Available Tasks ║         ║ SAS          ║ HDD   ║ DF05     ║ No             ║ Yes       ║ 558.38GB ║ 558.38GB             ║ 0.00GB                    ║ No        ║ DELL(tm)  ║ AL13SXB600N ║ 35H0A011F91A ║ PH0990FD755715418MHHA02 ║ 6.00 Gbps        ║ 6.00 Gbps     ║ 512B        ║ 04              ║ 14               ║ 2015             ║ 50000396281A7466 ║ Not Applicable                 ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║ Ok           ║ Physical Disk 0:1:1  ║ Online  ║ Spun Up      ║ Available Tasks ║         ║ SAS          ║ HDD   ║ DF05     ║ No             ║ Yes       ║ 558.38GB ║ 558.38GB             ║ 0.00GB                    ║ No        ║ DELL(tm)  ║ AL13SXB600N ║ 35L0A00JF91A ║ PH0990FD755715418MHNA02 ║ 6.00 Gbps        ║ 6.00 Gbps     ║ 512B        ║ 04              ║ 14               ║ 2015             ║ 50000396282282EE ║ Not Applicable                 ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║ Ok           ║ Physical Disk 0:1:2  ║ Online  ║ Spun Up      ║ Available Tasks ║         ║ SAS          ║ HDD   ║ DF05     ║ No             ║ Yes       ║ 558.38GB ║ 558.38GB             ║ 0.00GB                    ║ No        ║ DELL(tm)  ║ AL13SXB600N ║ 35H0A02BF91A ║ PH0990FD755715418MHGA02 ║ 6.00 Gbps        ║ 6.00 Gbps     ║ 512B        ║ 04              ║ 14               ║ 2015             ║ 50000396281A75D6 ║ Not Applicable                 ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║ Ok           ║ Physical Disk 0:1:3  ║ Online  ║ Spun Up      ║ Available Tasks ║         ║ SAS          ║ HDD   ║ DF05     ║ No             ║ Yes       ║ 558.38GB ║ 558.38GB             ║ 0.00GB                    ║ No        ║ DELL(tm)  ║ AL13SXB600N ║ 35J0A0DZF91A ║ PH0990FD755715418MH4A02 ║ 6.00 Gbps        ║ 6.00 Gbps     ║ 512B        ║ 04              ║ 14               ║ 2015             ║ 500003962820D1DA ║ Not Applicable                 ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║ Ok           ║ Physical Disk 0:1:4  ║ Online  ║ Spun Up      ║ Available Tasks ║         ║ SAS          ║ HDD   ║ DF02     ║ No             ║ Yes       ║ 558.38GB ║ 558.38GB             ║ 0.00GB                    ║ No        ║ DELL(tm)  ║ AL13SXB600N ║ 54S0A1J0F91A ║ PH0990FD7557145T193OA00 ║ 6.00 Gbps        ║ 6.00 Gbps     ║ 512B        ║ 05              ║ 22               ║ 2014             ║ 500003958839A9B6 ║ Not Applicable                 ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║ Ok           ║ Physical Disk 0:1:5  ║ Online  ║ Spun Up      ║ Available Tasks ║         ║ SAS          ║ HDD   ║ DF02     ║ No             ║ Yes       ║ 558.38GB ║ 558.38GB             ║ 0.00GB                    ║ No        ║ DELL(tm)  ║ AL13SXB600N ║ 54S0A1GGF91A ║ PH0990FD7557145T193VA00 ║ 6.00 Gbps        ║ 6.00 Gbps     ║ 512B        ║ 05              ║ 22               ║ 2014             ║ 500003958839A5A6 ║ Not Applicable                 ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║ Ok           ║ Physical Disk 0:1:6  ║ Online  ║ Spun Up      ║ Available Tasks ║         ║ SAS          ║ HDD   ║ DF02     ║ No             ║ Yes       ║ 558.38GB ║ 558.38GB             ║ 0.00GB                    ║ No        ║ DELL(tm)  ║ AL13SXB600N ║ 54S0A1FLF91A ║ PH0990FD7557145T1959A00 ║ 6.00 Gbps        ║ 6.00 Gbps     ║ 512B        ║ 05              ║ 22               ║ 2014             ║ 500003958839A4CA ║ Not Applicable                 ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║ Ok           ║ Physical Disk 0:1:7  ║ Online  ║ Spun Up      ║ Available Tasks ║         ║ SAS          ║ HDD   ║ DF02     ║ No             ║ Yes       ║ 558.38GB ║ 558.38GB             ║ 0.00GB                    ║ No        ║ DELL(tm)  ║ AL13SXB600N ║ 54S0A1G6F91A ║ PH0990FD7557145T193YA00 ║ 6.00 Gbps        ║ 6.00 Gbps     ║ 512B        ║ 05              ║ 22               ║ 2014             ║ 500003958839A55A ║ Not Applicable                 ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║ Ok           ║ Physical Disk 0:1:8  ║ Online  ║ Spun Up      ║ Available Tasks ║         ║ SAS          ║ HDD   ║ DF02     ║ No             ║ Yes       ║ 558.38GB ║ 558.38GB             ║ 0.00GB                    ║ No        ║ DELL(tm)  ║ AL13SXB600N ║ 54S0A1ELF91A ║ PH0990FD7557145T1946A00 ║ 6.00 Gbps        ║ 6.00 Gbps     ║ 512B        ║ 05              ║ 22               ║ 2014             ║ 500003958839A3DE ║ Not Applicable                 ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║ Ok           ║ Physical Disk 0:1:9  ║ Online  ║ Spun Up      ║ Available Tasks ║         ║ SAS          ║ HDD   ║ DF02     ║ No             ║ Yes       ║ 558.38GB ║ 558.38GB             ║ 0.00GB                    ║ No        ║ DELL(tm)  ║ AL13SXB600N ║ 54S0A1GSF91A ║ PH0990FD7557145T193QA00 ║ 6.00 Gbps        ║ 6.00 Gbps     ║ 512B        ║ 05              ║ 22               ║ 2014             ║ 500003958839A5E6 ║ Not Applicable                 ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║ Ok           ║ Physical Disk 0:1:10 ║ Online  ║ Spun Up      ║ Available Tasks ║         ║ SAS          ║ HDD   ║ DF02     ║ No             ║ Yes       ║ 558.38GB ║ 558.38GB             ║ 0.00GB                    ║ No        ║ DELL(tm)  ║ AL13SXB600N ║ 54S0A189F91A ║ PH0990FD7557145T195NA00 ║ 6.00 Gbps        ║ 6.00 Gbps     ║ 512B        ║ 05              ║ 22               ║ 2014             ║ 5000039588398956 ║ Not Applicable                 ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║ Ok           ║ Physical Disk 0:1:11 ║ Online  ║ Spun Up      ║ Available Tasks ║         ║ SAS          ║ HDD   ║ DF02     ║ No             ║ Yes       ║ 558.38GB ║ 558.38GB             ║ 0.00GB                    ║ No        ║ DELL(tm)  ║ AL13SXB600N ║ 54T0A0BFF91A ║ PH0990FD7557145T19KQA00 ║ 6.00 Gbps        ║ 6.00 Gbps     ║ 512B        ║ 05              ║ 22               ║ 2014             ║ 50000395883AE09E ║ Not Applicable                 ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║ Non-Critical ║ Physical Disk 0:1:12 ║ Foreign ║ Spun Up      ║ Available Tasks ║         ║ SAS          ║ HDD   ║ VT33     ║ No             ║ Yes       ║ 558.38GB ║ 0.00GB               ║ 558.38GB                  ║ No        ║ DELL(tm)  ║ ST600MP0005 ║ S7M08N18     ║ CN0V53007262255E017XA00 ║ 6.00 Gbps        ║ 12.00 Gbps    ║ 512B        ║ 07              ║ 19               ║ 2015             ║ 5000C50089527D41 ║ Not Applicable                 ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║ Non-Critical ║ Physical Disk 0:1:13 ║ Foreign ║ Spun Up      ║ Available Tasks ║         ║ SAS          ║ HDD   ║ VT33     ║ No             ║ Yes       ║ 558.38GB ║ 0.00GB               ║ 558.38GB                  ║ No        ║ DELL(tm)  ║ ST600MP0005 ║ S7M080V9     ║ CN0V53007262255D014SA00 ║ 6.00 Gbps        ║ 12.00 Gbps    ║ 512B        ║ 06              ║ 20               ║ 2015             ║ 5000C5008953E9D5 ║ Not Applicable                 ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║ Non-Critical ║ Physical Disk 0:1:14 ║ Foreign ║ Spun Up      ║ Available Tasks ║         ║ SAS          ║ HDD   ║ VT33     ║ No             ║ Yes       ║ 558.38GB ║ 0.00GB               ║ 558.38GB                  ║ No        ║ DELL(tm)  ║ ST600MP0005 ║ S7M07AV9     ║ CN0V530072622556005RA00 ║ 6.00 Gbps        ║ 12.00 Gbps    ║ 512B        ║ 06              ║ 19               ║ 2015             ║ 5000C5008940CCA1 ║ Not Applicable                 ║
╠══════════════╬══════════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════╬══════════════╬═══════╬══════════╬════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬════════════════════════════════╣
║ Non-Critical ║ Physical Disk 0:1:15 ║ Foreign ║ Spun Up      ║ Available Tasks ║         ║ SAS          ║ HDD   ║ VT33     ║ No             ║ Yes       ║ 558.38GB ║ 0.00GB               ║ 558.38GB                  ║ No        ║ DELL(tm)  ║ ST600MP0005 ║ S7M08M2A     ║ CN0V53007262255E00TEA00 ║ 6.00 Gbps        ║ 12.00 Gbps    ║ 512B        ║ 07              ║ 20               ║ 2015             ║ 5000C50089546C5D ║ Not Applicable                 ║
╚══════════════╩══════════════════════╩═════════╩══════════════╩═════════════════╩═════════╩══════════════╩═══════╩══════════╩════════════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩══════════════════════╩═══════════════════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═════════════╩══════════════╩═════════════════════════╩══════════════════╩═══════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════════╩══════════════════╩══════════════════╩══════════════════╩════════════════════════════════╝
```

the last 4 disks are the new disks i have installed.

Unsure if this is anything to do with it but also gives firmware warning.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clear foreign config would be in the controller BIOS while you boot. F2 to enter.

The screen should look that way;

[image]

To quote [someone](https://www.dell.com/community/PowerEdge-HDD-SCSI-RAID/How-to-clear-foreign-state-hard-drive-in-T630-with-PERC-H730/td-p/4628114);

> If you are in the Ctrl-R management screen, stay on the first tab.  Do
>   not Ctrl-N to the Foreign Mgmt tab.
>
> Highlight the PERC (top Line), press F2 and select Foreign Management.
>   There you can clear all Foreign settings.  I had the same issue and
>   could only blink/no blink from the Foreign Mgmt tab.

Comment: Thanks.  Can i keep my existing VD setup by choosing this option?

Comment: @BrendanGooden Yes, as the option only impact foreign config, but I would suggest to be sure you have a good backup and that your controller is updated to the latest firmware too. To be sure no bug happen when you will issue the command. The important is to be sure your raid is ok too, as if one of your disk fall into foreign state for a unknown reason, the clear foreign would clear it too.